# How to format a response from a get request to a 3rd party Api by id?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core 3.1 api project and I need to get a single vehicle back by using the id. I have made the models to match the data from the Api.

This is what I have so far...

```
    public class SamsaraGpsVehicleInfo
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("externalIds")]
        public ExternalIds ExternalIds { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("gateway")]
        public Gateway Gateway { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("harshAccelerationSettingType")]
        public string HarshAccelerationSettingType { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("licensePlate")]
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("make")]
        public string Make { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("serial")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("vin")]
        public string Vin { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("year")]
        public string Year { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("vehicleRegulationMode")]
        public string VehicleRegulationMode { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("createdAtTime")]
        public DateTime CreatedAtTime { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("updatedAtTime")]
        public DateTime UpdatedAtTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class ExternalIds
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("samsara.serial")]
        public string SamsaraSerial { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("samsara.vin")]
        public string SamsaraVin { get; set; }
    }

    public class Gateway
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("serial")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }

    public class SamsaraGpsVehicleList
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("data")]
        public ICollection<SamsaraGpsVehicleInfo> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Which I make a call with my client like so:

```
        public async Task<ICollection<SamsaraGpsVehicleInfo>> GetVehicles()
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _client.GetAsync("fleet/vehicles");

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var list = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<SamsaraGpsVehicleList>();
                    return list.Data;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

This returns a nice formatted response when I call it from my controller code:

```
        [HttpGet("samsara")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetVehicles(
            [FromServices] SamsaraGpsService samsaraGps)
        {
            var results = await samsaraGps.GetVehicles();

            return Ok(results);
```

and my result is this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "externalIds": {
            "samsaraSerial": null,
            "samsaraVin": null
        },
        "gateway": {
            "serial": "G2PV-5GN-98C",
            "model": "VG54NA"
        },
        "harshAccelerationSettingType": "automatic",
        "id": "28111111111117",
        "licensePlate": "UOG 18",
        "make": "CHRYSLER",
        "model": "Pacifica",
        "name": "UOG 18",
        "notes": "",
        "serial": "G2123123C",
        "vin": "2C4123213213515",
        "year": "2019",
        "vehicleRegulationMode": "regulated",
        "createdAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z",
        "updatedAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z"
    },
    {
        "externalIds": {
            "samsaraSerial": null,
            "samsaraVin": null
        },
        "gateway": {
            "serial": "G111-111-11M",
            "model": "V1111A"
        },
        "harshAccelerationSettingType": "automatic",
        "id": "2811111111118",
        "licensePlate": "UOG 25",
        "make": "CHRYSLER",
        "model": "Pacifica",
        "name": "UOG 25",
        "notes": "",
        "serial": "GJJJJJJPM",
        "vin": "211111111122",
        "year": "2019",
        "vehicleRegulationMode": "regulated",
        "createdAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z",
        "updatedAtTime": "2022-08-08T20:55:04Z"
    },
    {
        "externalIds": {
            "samsaraSerial": null,
            "samsaraVin": null
        },
        "gateway": {
            "serial": "GXGB-111-111",
            "model": "VG54NA"
        },
        "harshAccelerationSettingType": "automatic",
        "id": "2819873793099",
        "licensePlate": "TEST",
        "make": "CHRYSLER",
        "model": "Town and Country",
        "name": "New Van",
        "notes": "",
        "serial": "GHGHGHGHGH",
        "vin": "2C4G4G4G1",
        "year": "2014",
        "vehicleRegulationMode": "regulated",
        "createdAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z",
        "updatedAtTime": "2021-10-13T17:10:56Z"
    }
]
```

which is perfect.

However I need to get a single vehicle. So I have this code:

```
        public async Task<SamsaraVehicle> GetVehicleById(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _client.GetAsync($"fleet/vehicles/{id}");

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var vehicle = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<SamsaraVehicle>();

                    return vehicle;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

and this model for the vehicle:

```
    public class SamsaraVehicle
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("vin")]
        public string Vin { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("serial")]
        public string Serial { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("make")]
        public string Make { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("model")]
        public string Model { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("year")]
        public string Year { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("harshAccelerationSettingType")]
        public string HarshAccelerationSettingType { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("licensePlate")]
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("externalIds")]
        public ExternalIds ExternalIds { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("gateway")]
        public Gateway Gateway { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("vehicleRegulationMode")]
        public string VehicleRegulationMode { get; set; }
    }

    public class SamsaraSingleVehicle
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("data")]
        public ICollection<SamsaraVehicle> Data { get; set; }
    }
```

However I can not figure out how to get this vehicle back by id. If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: So what exactly is not working for you?

Comment: Whenever I try to get the vehicle by id back I get null back for every Json object for SamsaraVehicle

Comment: And what json string is returned by the `fleet/vehicles/{id}` endpoint ?

Comment: the debugger says that the id: "281474979033097", result: StatusCode:200. Then when I return vehicle im just getting an empty SamsaraVehicle object.

Comment: Again. Please read `result.Content` as string and add it to the question. Your previous comment does not answer my question.

Comment: Even though its difficult for someone to find the bug here, i think you must read as `<SamsaraSingleVehicle>` and then to get the single result of data collection

Comment: Yea so I was just debugging and I get a 200 response and its showing id = 23746487 (Which is correct). But then it hits the catch at the end and returns null.

Comment: What exception did you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand you modify your codes:

```
var vehicle = await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<SamsaraVehicle>();
```

to

```
var jsonstring = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SamsaraVehicle>(jsonstring);
```

When you debug, you would check the jsonstring :

[image]

[image]

then you could modify the propery of the model accroding to the string